# Pod with S3FS stuck in terminating status

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, kubernetes, s3fs

I need to mount an s3 bucket in a kubernetes pod. I am using [this guide](https://blog.meain.io/2020/mounting-s3-bucket-kube/) to help me. It works perfectly, however, the pod is stuck indefinitely in the status of "terminating" when giving the command to delete the pod. I don't know why that is.

Here the .yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: worker
spec:
      volumes:
        - name: mntdatas3fs
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: devfuse
          hostPath:
            path: /dev/fuse
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: s3-test
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mntdatas3fs
            mountPath: /var/s3fs:shared
      - name: s3fs
        image: meain/s3-mounter
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        env:
          - name: S3_REGION
            value: "us-east-1"
          - name: S3_BUCKET
            value: "xxxxxxx"
          - name: AWS_KEY
            value: "xxxxxx"
          - name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
            value: "xxxxxx"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: devfuse
            mountPath: /dev/fuse
          - name: mntdatas3fs
            mountPath: /var/s3fs:shared
```

Here the Dockerfile of meain/s3-mounter used by s3fs container

```
FROM alpine:3.3

ENV MNT_POINT /var/s3fs

ARG S3FS_VERSION=v1.86

RUN apk --update --no-cache add fuse alpine-sdk automake autoconf libxml2-dev fuse-dev curl-dev git bash; \
    git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse.git; \
    cd s3fs-fuse; \
    git checkout tags/${S3FS_VERSION}; \
    ./autogen.sh; \
    ./configure --prefix=/usr; \
    make; \
    make install; \
    make clean; \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*; \
    apk del git automake autoconf;

RUN mkdir -p "$MNT_POINT"

COPY run.sh run.sh
CMD ./run.sh
```

Here the run.sh copied into the container

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

echo "$AWS_KEY:$AWS_SECRET_KEY" > passwd && chmod 600 passwd
s3fs "$S3_BUCKET" "$MNT_POINT" -o passwd_file=passwd  && tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: Could you try testing with the latest s3fs version 1.89?

Comment: I have a similar issue; I also did try with 1.89 and got the same result the pod will stick forever in the `terminating` state.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem with a very similiar setup. s3fs mounts s3 to /var/s3fs. The mount has to be unmounted before the pod can happily be terminated. This is done done with: `umount /var/s3fs`. See https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/s3fs.1.html

So in your case adding

```
lifecycle:
  preStop:
    exec:
      command: ["sh","-c","umount /var/mnts3fs"]
```

Should fix it.